# All my Icons on ios are blue even though I defined an icon theme in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently trying to use the `flutter_platform_widgets` package

I have my **material_light_theme** defined as shown below:

```
ThemeData materialLightTheme = ThemeData.light().copyWith(
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: AppColors.lightThemeBackgroundColor,
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    primaryColor: AppColors.primaryColor,
    primaryColorDark: AppColors.lightThemeBackgroundColor,
    cardColor: AppColors.lightThemeCardColor,
    colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(
      primary: AppColors.primaryColor,
      secondary: AppColors.secondaryColor,
      background: AppColors.lightThemeBackgroundColor,
    ),
    dialogTheme: DialogTheme(
      titleTextStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins().copyWith(color: Colors.black),
      contentTextStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins().copyWith(
        color: Colors.black45,
      ),
    ),
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
      systemOverlayStyle: const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: AppColors.lightThemeStatusBarColor,
        statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark,
        statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
        systemNavigationBarColor: AppColors.lightThemeNavigationBarColor,
        systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
      ),
      elevation: 0,
      backgroundColor: AppColors.lightThemeBackgroundColor,
      toolbarTextStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins().copyWith(
        color: AppColors.gray900,
        fontSize: 18.0,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
      ),
      titleTextStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins().copyWith(
        color: AppColors.gray900,
        fontSize: 18.0,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
      ),
      iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: AppColors.gray900, size: 25),
    ),
    inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
      errorStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins().copyWith(
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      labelStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins().copyWith(fontSize: 16),
      enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue.shade700, width: 2),
      ),
      focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue.shade400, width: 1),
      ),
      errorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red.shade700, width: 1),
      ),
      focusedErrorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red.shade400, width: 1),
      ),
      disabledBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 1),
      ),
    ),
    textTheme: GoogleFonts.poppinsTextTheme()
        .apply(displayColor: Colors.black, bodyColor: AppColors.gray900),
    iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: AppColors.gray900, size: 25), //Notice the icon theme here
    elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
      style: ButtonStyle(
        textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(
          GoogleFonts.poppinsTextTheme()
              .bodyMedium!
              .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
        ),
        foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.white),
      ),
    ),
    textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
      style: ButtonStyle(
        textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(
          GoogleFonts.poppinsTextTheme()
              .bodyMedium!
              .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Then I created my **cupertino_light_theme** as well and merged it with the material_light_theme above:

```
const lightDefaultCupertinoTheme =
        CupertinoThemeData(brightness: Brightness.light);
    return MaterialBasedCupertinoThemeData(
        materialTheme: materialLightTheme.copyWith( //Merged here
      cupertinoOverrideTheme: CupertinoThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        barBackgroundColor: materialTheme.colorScheme.background,
        textTheme: CupertinoTextThemeData(
          primaryColor: Colors.black,
          navActionTextStyle:
              lightDefaultCupertinoTheme.textTheme.navActionTextStyle.copyWith(
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          navLargeTitleTextStyle: lightDefaultCupertinoTheme
              .textTheme.navLargeTitleTextStyle
              .copyWith(
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
```

then I connected them all in my main.dart file as shown below:

```
 builder: (context) => PlatformTheme(
                themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
                materialLightTheme: materialLightTheme,
                materialDarkTheme: materialDarkTheme,
                cupertinoLightTheme: cupertinoLightTheme,
                cupertinoDarkTheme: cupertinoDarkTheme,
                matchCupertinoSystemChromeBrightness: true
               .....
```

When I ran my app, the **icon theme** came out as expected on Android but on ios all my icons are blue, which is the primary color of my app. So, it seems the cupertino theme is not picking up my custom defined **icon theme** above.

Please how do I fix this? Thank you